# Selenium. Mouse sobre elemento no despliega el contenido

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, hover

Estoy realizando scrapes de datos en la página http://www.nowgoal.com. El problema que tengo es que si bajas en la página principal, te aparecen los resultados de los partidos del día ya finalizados, y si colocas el ratón sobre el resultado te aparece una tabla. Por el motivo que sea soy incapaz de hacer funcionar el código de Python para obtener dicha tabla. Estoy haciendo esto

Obtengo la lista de nodos, siendo cada nodo un partido.

Obtengo, dentro del nodo, el elemento del resultado haciendo

```
score=node.find_element_by_css('.red')
```

Situo el ratón sobre el elemento score, busco la tabla, e imprimo el resultado obtenido

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(score).perform()
TabScore=browser.find_element_by_id('winScore')
print(TabScore.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

Lo que obtengo, no obstante, es el elemento como si la acción de situar el ratón sobre el elemento no hubiese tenido lugar.

```
>> <div id="winScore" style="position:absolute; z-index:8;top:100px;left:100px;visibility:hidden;" onmouseover="MM_showHideLayers('winScore','','show')" onmouseout="hiddendetail()"></div>
```

Aclarar que el elemento score es el correcto. Si hago `score.text` o `score.click()` el resultado coincide, y ejecuta la acción correspondiente a clickar sobre el resultado, que es abrir una pestaña nueva, por lo que el fallo debe estar al realizar la linea de ActionChains, pero no consigo entender por qué no funciona.

PD: He probado a hacer `time.sleep(20)` entre ActionChains y la query de la tabla, con el mismo resultado.

Comment: La accion de mouse over en firefox a mi no terminó de funcionarme. Lo has probado con chrome ?

Comment: Si, debería haberlo añadido al post, pero yo estoy utilizando chromedriver